# Binding hudson build number in C# project

Tags: msbuild, hudson

Is there a way to bind the hudson successful build's number in the C# WPF application?
Meaning, on running the exe after building I want to show the build number say 10 in my application somewhere. 
In project configuration file, I have used ${BUILD_NUMBER}, that a hudson understands and creates a build with the revision number. If I build the Project revision # 10, I get 10.exe.
Can I have something that will show this number somewhere in my application?
Hope I am clear. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Hudson is, but MSBUILD can do this. See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2005/11/11/how-to-update-assembly-version-numbers-with-msbuild.aspx)

Comment: I included the AssemblyInfo tmport and Tag
<AssemblyInfo.... > I bounded build number to ${Build_number} of hudson. Now it got replaced. But my major.minor.Revision.build is giving me < . . buildnumber. > i.e: major, minor and revision places are empty.

Comment: If you have the Version Number plug in for Jenkins, you have specify the version as 1.2.3.${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}.  Then in your task to UpdateAssemblyInfo, you have to parse the version number into major, minor, build and revision.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the AssemblyInfo Task, which is part of the MSBuild Community Tasks library to update the AssemblyInfo.cs file for your project.

```
<AssemblyInfo 
    CodeLanguage="CS" 
    OutputFile="MyApplication\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" 
    AssemblyVersion="@(VersionMajor).@(VersionMinor).@(VersionBuild).@(VersionRevision)" 
    AssemblyFileVersion="@(VersionMajor).@(VersionMinor).@(VersionBuild).@(VersionRevision)" 
    />
```